# Overriding a .phtml file in custom theme doesn't work

Tags: magento2, module, overrides, localisation

I've been trying to override D:\Projects\PMM-M2\public_html\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\success.phtml by placing the file in my custom theme at location D:\Projects\PMM-M2\public_html\app\design\frontend\Perfectmakeupmirrors\argento-luxury-custom\Magento_Checkout\templates\success.phtml.

I need to change the line `<p><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('We\'ll email you an order confirmation with details and tracking info.')) ?></p>` to `<p><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Within 10 minutes we\'ll send an email to you with your <strong>%1</strong> and complete details.<br />When your order ships we\'ll email tracking information to you.', 'order'), ['strong','br']) ?></p><?php endif;?>`

This is not happening. Is there anything wrong in how I'm overriding .phtml file in my custom theme?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The template path seems correct assuming you are using the correct theme

- app\design\frontend\Perfectmakeupmirrors\argento-luxury-custom\Magento_Checkout\templates\success.phtml

Could you check within your code base to see if any other module is changing the template path, by searching for `checkout.success`

Example

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.success" template="MagePal_EnhancedSuccessPage::checkout/success.phtml">
```

Comment: Hi, I found the following references from 4 different modules.

Comment: <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" name="checkout.success.print.button" template="Magento_Checkout::button.phtml"/>
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" name="checkout.success" template="Magento_Checkout::success.phtml" cacheable="false">

Comment: <block class="Magento\Downloadable\Block\Checkout\Success" name="downloadable.checkout.success" template="Magento_Downloadable::checkout/success.phtml"/>
<block class="Magento\Downloadable\Block\Checkout\Success" name="downloadable.checkout.success" template="Magento_Downloadable::checkout/success.phtml"/>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.success" template="Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend::success.phtml">